# ¿Obtener fechas que estan entre una fecha de inicio y una fecha final Moment js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que estoy usando momentjs para manipulación de fechas en mi aplicativo, mi problema es que necesito comparar una fecha de inicio y una fecha final,luego llenar un array con las fechas que se encuentran entre estas, ejemplo si tengo una fecha de inicio de 2018/09/07 y una fecha final de 2018/09/10 entonces los valores de mi array tendrían que ser los siguientes:
array = ['2018/09/08','2018/09/09'], probe usando la funcion diff que encontré en la documentación:

```
var moment = require('moment');
           let init_date = moment(self.crono.init_date);
           let end_date = moment(self.crono.end_date);

           console.log(end_date.diff(init_date, 'days'), ' dias de diferencia');
```

pero al hacer esto obtengo los días de diferencia, mas no obtengo las fechas como tal que necesito.

Como podría llenar el array con las fechas que necesito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería servirte algo así:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    var ini = moment(document.getElementById('start').value);
    var fin = moment(document.getElementById('end').value);
    
    if(ini != undefined && fin != undefined){
      $('ul').empty();
      var fechas = [];
      
      while (ini.isSameOrBefore(fin)) {
        fechas.push(ini.format('M/D/YYYY'));
        ini.add(1, 'days');
      }
      
      $.each(fechas, function(i, v){
        var d = moment(v).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
        $(".row ul").append('<li class="text-success">' + d + '</li>');
        //console.log(d);
      })
    }
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="control-label col-md-4">Inicio</label>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="control-label col-md-4">Fin</label>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="end">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-8" style="margin-top:33px; margin-left:-20px" id="btn" onclick="obtener()">Obtener</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row mt-2">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Nos comentas que tal te va

Comment: Me funciono, como podría hacer, que me muestre en el console.log la fecha desde la que inicia y la fecha hasta la que llega?

Comment: dentro del $.each imprime la variable d.. con eso basta.. de hecho es la línea que deje comentada ;)

Comment: si ya lo hice pero, no me imprime desde la fecha de inicio

Comment: Ahhhh ahora entendí, quieres incluir las fechas del filtro, edito la respuesta

Comment: Exacto, muchas gracias

Comment: Listo! El único cambio que realice fue en el `while`, donde le aumento un día por cada iteración a la **fecha inicio**, además de quitar la condición `ini.add(1, 'days').diff(fin) < 0`

Comment: Listo ya lo probé y funciona de maravilla, muchas gracias.