# Cómo puedo con un input type="date" obtener un resultado en un input type="text"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Me gustaría saber si el ingresar una fecha, en este caso, "fecha de vencimiento de una credencial", con base en esa fecha determinar si esta vencida o es vigente, dependiendo siempre de la fecha actual.

**Actualización**

```js
function DocUbicacion1() {

  var doc = document.getElementById("doc");

  if (doc1.value == ""){

        document.getElementById("credencial1").innerHTML = "<option value='' >--Seleccione una opción--</option>";

    }

    if (doc1.value == "Se encuentra en el puesto"){

        document.getElementById("credencial1").innerHTML = "<input value='' placeholder='--Seleccone el estado de la crdencial--' class='form-control' readonly>";

        document.getElementById("credencial2").innerHTML = "<input type='date' id='start' name='fecha_vencimiento_credencial' class='form-control' title='ingrese fecha de vencimiento de la credencial' placeholder='Día'>";

    }

    if (doc1.value == "No se encuentra en el puesto"){

        document.getElementById("credencial1").innerHTML = "<option value='No registra / permiso ausente'>No registra / permiso ausente</option>";

        document.getElementById("credencial2").innerHTML = "<input value='Credencial ausente' name='fecha_vencimiento_credencial' class='form-control' placeholder='Día' readonly>";
    }

    if (doc1.value == "Credencial provisional"){

        document.getElementById("credencial1").innerHTML = "<option value='Credencial provisional'>Credencial provisional</option>";

        document.getElementById("credencial2").innerHTML = "<input value='Credencial provicional' class='form-control' readonly>";
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label for="exampleInputFile">Ubicación del Documento</label>
<select onchange="DocUbicacion1()" id="doc1" for="exampleInputEmail" title="Ingrese la unicación del documento" class="form-control" name='credencial'>
<option value=''>--Seleccione una opción--</option>
<option value="Se encuentra en el puesto" >Se encuentra en el puesto</option>
<option value="No se encuentra en el puesto" >No se encuentra en el puesto</option>
<option value="Credencial provisional">Credencial provisional</option>
</select>

 <label for="exampleInputFile">Fecha de vencimiento</label>
<div class="col" id="credencial2">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="--Seleccione ubicación del documento--" readonly>
</div>
<br> 

<label for="exampleInputFile">Estado de la Credencial:</label>
<select  name="estado_credencial" id="credencial1" title="ingrese el estado de la credencial" class="form-control" >
    <option value='' >--Seleccione ubicación del documento--</option>
    <option value='Vigente' selected>Vigente</option>
    <option value='Vencida' selected>Vencida</option>
</select>
<br>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentando? ¿En qué parte del código estás teniendo problemas?

Comment: @A.Cedano Había visto este post [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195071/obtener-fechas-que-estan-entre-una-fecha-de-inicio-y-una-fecha-final-moment-js], pero pues, nunca he trabajado con fechas en javascript o jquery y apenas estoy en aprendiendo, pero la verdad no se si se pueda, tienes alguna idea de como podría hacerlo?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo intentar con moment.js: https://momentjs.com/

serial algo asi:

si estas usando jquery puede usar esto:

```
// con jQuery
// var expira =$('#start').val();

// sin JQuery
//var expira = document.getElementById('start').value

var fecha_actual = '2019-2-04';

var a = moment(expira);
var b = moment(fecha_actual)

a.isBefore(b); //returns true or false dependiendo si la fecha ya paso o no.
```

Usando solo javascript

```
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', function() {
    // se ejecuta cuando el datepicker cambie de valor
    var input_date = this.value;
    console.log(input_date)
    var now = new Date();
    var date_selected = new Date(input_date);
    if (now > date_selected) { console.log('fecha actual es mayor a la fecha selecionada') }
    else { console.log('fecha seleccionada valida')}
​
})
```

Creo que aca esta funcionando https://jsfiddle.net/L405xmgk/15/ con javascript.

Para user momentjs necessitaras jQuery
https://jquery.com/

Pero en el ejemplo use solo javascript sin ninguna libreria.

Saludos

Comment: Voy a probar y ya te comento como me va, gracias por el consejo.

Comment: Hay que señalar, @RafaelGaitan, que `moment.js` es una librería aparte, y que debes incluirla en la cabecera del HTML para que el ejemplo funcione. Gabriel, puedes hacer un fragmento de código de prueba, usando las herramientas de Stackoverflow.

Comment: Tengo un incoveniente con mi formulario, y es que tengo unos condicionales, que cuando la credencial esta en el "puesto", entonces si me muestra el input type="date", y le permite ingresar la fecha de vendimiento, pero si no esta en el puesto, entonces se envia como permiso ausente, pero los 2 tienen el mismo name.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que mejor agrego el código y me dices que tal...

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, muy amable...

Answer (score 0):

si es para fecha puedes usar type date, asi

```
<input type="date= id="fecha" name="fecha">
```

si deseas capturar el valor en jquery es de la siguiente manera

```
var fecha=$('#fecha').val();
```

y si deseas capturar el valor en php el input debe estar dentro de un formulario con method="POST" de preferencia y lo capturas asi

```
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
```