# ¿Cómo obtener rangos de fechas en base a una fecha inicial?

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-6

mi problema es el siguiente, estoy realizando un sistema de prestamos por cuotas por lo que el usuario puede elegir si desea que el pago sea diario, semanal, mensual o anual, automaticamente le tiene que mostrar las fechas en las cuales son sus pagos, es decir si elige diario y el prestamo inicia hoy y elige a 2 cuotas deberia mostrar algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no logro hacerlo, estoy intentando de las siguientes formas:

**1)**

```
let due = totalAmount / jsonData.dues
    let dues = []
    let date = new Date(jsonData.date)
    let payments = []

    for (let i = 1; i <= jsonData.dues; i++) {
        dues.push(due)
        let dia = sumarDias(date,1)
        payments.push(dia)
    }

    console.log(payments);
```

**2)**

```
let due = totalAmount / jsonData.dues
    let dues = []
    let date = new Date(jsonData.date)
    let payments = [date]

    for (let i = 1; i <= jsonData.dues; i++) {
        dues.push(due)
        let dia = sumarDias(payments[i],1)
        payments.push(dia)
    }

    console.log(payments);
```

En ambos casos solo me muestra la ultima fecha de pago que seria el 24 de forma repetida, es decir si son 2 cuotas me mostrara la ultima fecha 2 veces.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi función sumarDias:

```
function sumarDias(fecha, dias){
fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
return fecha;
}
```

Comment: Hola, podrias mostrar que hay en jsonData?

Comment: [Esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195071/obtener-fechas-que-estan-entre-una-fecha-de-inicio-y-una-fecha-final-moment-js/195079#195079) respuesta te sirve?