# Obtener las 2 fechas de DatePicker

Tags: jquery

Encontre un DatePicker en internet que funciona con el siguiente codigo:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
</script>
```

Y necesito obtener los valores seleccionados con Jquery para realizar la consulta a la base de datos.
El problema es que las variables start y end son "privadas", es decir como puedo accesarlas desde fuera del metodo del datepicker?

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
$("#buscar").on("click",function(){
        var fechai = moment(start,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss a').format('DD-MM-YY'); 
        var fechaf = moment(end,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss a').format('DD-MM-YY'); 
});
```

Pero me toma las fechas preestablecidas por defecto.

Comment: Ésta respuesta te puede ser útil: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/195079/155688

Comment: Y esta en javascript no jquery,pero el ejemplo tiene dos selectores de fecha no uno solo con 2 fechas como tengo yo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651943/getting-the-value-of-daterangepicker-bootstrap quizas ahi encuentre la solucion.